# How to call nested Async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to know what is best way to call nested async methods, if I want both methods to be async. 
**First:** Caller method must just return `Task`

```
public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
{
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
public Task UpdateAsync(List<TEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
    {
        BeforeUpdate(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    return SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**Second:** Caller method must have an async-`await` as called method

```
public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
{
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
public async Task UpdateAsync(List<TEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
    {
        BeforeUpdate(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should not use `async/await`, unless there are pieces in those methods you have not shown.

In other words, this is how these methods should be written:

```
public Task SaveChangesAsync()
{
    return Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
public Task UpdateAsync(List<TEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
    {
        BeforeUpdate(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    return SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This is basically option 3 which you did not show, no trace of `async/await` at all.

The reason for this is that the way the code will execute is as follows:

1. It will execute all the parts of `UpdateAsync` leading up to the await, on the calling thread, which means the `foreach`-loop will be executing on the calling thread
2. It will execute the call to `SaveChangesAsync()` up until it returns, still on the calling thread
3. `SaveChangesAsync` will call into `Context.SaveChangesAsync()` until it returns, still on the calling thread

In short, **all the work** of these methods have already been done on the calling thread, what is left is **only** the async-ness of `Context.SaveChangesAsync`. If you drop `async/await` completely and simply return the task that wrap that async-ness all the way back out, you have not sacrificed any functionality but you have removed all the complexity that the compiler generates for you with an `async/await` method.

The general rule is this:

> Unless you need to do something **after** the async method returns, don't use `async/await`

Since both your methods ends right after the call to the async method, you're better off just returning the tasks involved instead and not using `async/await`.

Comment: `Unless you need to do something after the async method returns, don't use async/await` is a great rule.

Answer (score 4):

An `await` can work on any `Task`. It doesn't have to be the result of an `async` method. In fact, it doesn't have to be the result of any method at all.

That said, I recommend that any methods with non-trivial logic in them should use `async`/`await`:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(List<TEntity> entities)
{
  foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
  {
    BeforeUpdate(entity);
    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
  }
  await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This is because `async` captures exceptions in the method body and places them on the returned `Task`, which is expected behavior when calling task-returning methods. If you elide the `async`/`await` here, then any exceptions from `BeforeUpdate` or setting `State` would be thrown directly rather than placed on the `Task`.

On the other hand, your calling method is trivial, so you can elide `async`/`await` there:

```
public Task SaveChangesAsync()
{
  return Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you go async, `await` and `async` need to be used through the call stack, otherwise the code will not be executed asynchronously. So use `async` on both methods.

> If an async method doesn’t use an await operator to mark a suspension
>   point, the method executes as a synchronous method does, despite the
>   async modifier

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is [Async All the Way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) Down, which means you have to take the second approach!
The first approach is not going to work as expected because you are not synchronizing with the current context and just returning a `task`. Now your task will be completed sometime in future but you won't be able to get it's result (or even any exception) again because you didn't synchronize with the current synchronization context!